# different data while same ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

hey there i did some photo, take a look:

[image: first one]

AND:

[image: second one]

could anyone explain me why, its:

```
[\"0.0\"]
```

should be :

```
[0.0]
```

any ideas? greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not coming from the ajax request instead it is related to your server side script, check out the type of the value you put (`0.0`) if:

1. its a numeric value
2. if its a string check what is contains (perhaps it has the " from something you miss)

---

I will try to explain my idea with a sample code as requested.

Lets say your PHP script returns something like

```
$x = 0.3; // or any number you want to return
echo json_encode( array( x => "[$x]" ) );
```

this script will output:

> {"x":"[0.3]"}

(Which is expected thing I assume)

but if the $x value is different, like in this example:

```
$x = '"0.3"'; // or any number you want to return
echo json_encode( array( x => "[$x]" ) );
```

The output would be:

> {"x":"["0.3"]"}

So the `$x` content that is giving the wrong output not the ajax request itself

---

###update:
You can use this function [floatval](https://www.php.net/floatval) to extract the numeric value out of the string or use `REGEX` if it doesn't work

For regex I would propose something like:

```
$x = '"0.3"'; // or any number you want to return

preg_match( '/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/', $x , $m);
$x =  $m[0];
echo json_encode( array( x => "[$x]" ) );
```

Comment: ehm i dont understand what you mean..could you post sample code?

Comment: What language are you using in the server side?  `PHP`, `ASP` or something else?!!

Comment: because as I said, the problem might be coming from your php script, I'll post PHP code to explain what I mean, just give me a moment okay :) ?

Comment: yes i understood what you mean, one more question: if there is something like $x = '"0.3"'; , how to change this to $x = 0.3 using php?

Comment: @user2999787 you can use this function [floatval](http://us2.php.net/floatval) Check it out, and if you have any more question just ask :), and thanks for the upvote and accept

Comment: @user2999787, check my last edit, I've add a sample of code you can use to extract the `$x` number in case `floatval` didn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is just an escape character which escapes `"`.

So everytime you have a `"`, it is prepended as `\"`

Comment: yeah and why there is no escape character when this is send? : data {"x":"[0.3]"} could u explain?

Comment: It looks like your value is a string `"0.3"` (hence the quotes) but not `0.3` or `[0.3]`. observe no quotes for the latter 2 values.